# Procedure to auto-increment the trackbar in delphi

Tags: delphi

I am finding difficulty in finding a solution for this. I am designing a simulation application and need to display graphs at certain intervals. I have a `TTrackBar`. I want to increment its values with a delay of 500ms between each step increase.

I wrote this method which is called from `FormShow(Sender: TObject)` procedure

```
PROCEDURE playTrackBar (t: Real);
VAR
  v   : REAL;
BEGIN
  v   := t;
  while <CONDITION> do
  BEGIN
    v := v + 1;
    if (v >= Form4.TrackBar1.Max) then
    BEGIN
      v := 0;
    END;
    Form4.TrackBar1.Value := v;
    sleep(500);
  END;
END;
```

I was looking for an event like `trackbar.isClicked()` which returns a boolean value so I could stop the while loop, but couldn't find any such function. When I used the value `true` at `<CONDITION>`, the application crashed (possibly because of the infinite loop).

Need some help in finding what the `<CONDITION>` should be. Would accept if any other possible solutions to achieve auto-incrementing/auto-playing the track bar is provided.

Comment: Seems it is work for `TTimer` rather than for `Sleep`

Comment: How will the video play if your code spends all its time executing this loop?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I am not actually designing a video player. I was just stating an example where trackbar has an auto play. I am designing a simulation application and need to show graphs at each interval. (Added this to question. Thank you.)

Comment: The problem remains. How is your program going to respond to input when it spends its entire life inside that loop?

Comment: David wants to say : put this code inside a thread. Your code won't work as you expect in a single thread app. Sleep gives a chance to the other threads to do their work. But if there is just one thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A program must not allocate all CPU resources. When you update a GUI component or wants input from the user, there must be time for the system to reflect those events. A sleep call is not the correct way to do this.

Use a [TTimer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TTimer) event to animate the trackbar.
Put the `TTimer` on your form and set `Enabled` to false. Add an OnTimer event:

```
procedure TMyForm.OnTimer1(Sender: TObject);
var
  trackPos : Integer;
begin
  trackPos := TrackBar1.Value;
  if trackPos >= TrackBar1.Max then begin // Time to stop animation
    Timer1.Enabled := False;  // Or move this line to another event
    TrackBar1.Value := 0; // Reset the value to zero
    Exit; 
  end;
  TrackBar1.Value := trackPos + 1;
end;
```

In your form `Show` event, set the update interval and start the timer:

```
procedure TMyForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TrackBar1.Max := 200;
  TrackBar1.Value := 0;
  Timer1.Interval := 500;
  Timer1.Enabled := True; // Start the animation     
end;
```

The animation stops when the trackbar value reaches the maximum value.

---

If you want to stop the animation by an event (user clicks on something),
just move the timer enabled setting into this event.